# Unable to see Case records into related list in the account

Tags: administration, user-admin, admin

I have created case record for an account but I am not able to see those records under the account related list section. My profile is System admin.
Could you please help me.

[image]

Comment: And the related case list is added to the page layout of your account?

Comment: @LievenJuwet Yes, I have added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There're two possible problems:

- Something wrong with your permissions.
- Something wrong with your record.

Permissions: just open the record you've created and if you could view it - than at least you have an access to the record so, it most likely not permission problems. Hence, something's wrong with your record. Check carefully the Id of the parent account - it could be that you have two accounts with similar name.

Well, that's all what I think could be the problems. Never heard it could be that you have an access to Case record and its definetly linked to your account and it's not shown in related list.